# HTML flashing text colors

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, colors

This is quite an unusual request, but..

Is there anyway to make some text alternate between 2 colors every second?

So it appears as though it's flashing between say... red and grey? I don't mean background color, I mean the actual font color. I'm assuming it would need javascript or something.

Is there any simple way to do that?

(disregarding the fact it could look ugly)

### UPDATE

Id like to call to this function several times on my page, each one passing along a different color to alternate with GREY

.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per your request:

```
    function flashtext(ele,col) {
    var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById( ele ).style.color;

      if (tmpColCheck === 'silver') {
        document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = col;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( ele ).style.color = 'silver';
      }
    } 

    setInterval(function() {
        flashtext('flashingtext','red');
        flashtext('flashingtext2','blue');
        flashtext('flashingtext3','green');
    }, 500 ); //set an interval timer up to repeat the function
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/rXVUh/14/

Comment: thank you. I want to make it so I can call to the function with a color, and it'll alternate that color with grey. I'm useless in javascript

Comment: and there will be several texts on the page with different color flashes.

Comment: Added new function, works nicer than the previous one - and again edited.

Comment: thanks im just trying to work it with my page. My page is in php and dynamic, so there could be anywhere from 1 to 100 different texts that this function would need to be run on.

Comment: Well, I would use CSS classes on anything that needed to run the FlashingText function, then use jQuery to apply the function `each()` of the elements in existence... But that's just me... ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an easy way to do it with plain JavaScript:

```
function flash() {
    var text = document.getElementById('foo');
    text.style.color = (text.style.color=='red') ? 'green':'red';
}
var clr = setInterval(flash, 1000);
```

This will alternate the color of the text between red and green every second. **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/che7Q/)** example.

Here's another example where you can set the colors of different elements:

```
function flash(el, c1, c2) {
    var text = document.getElementById(el);
    text.style.color = (text.style.color == c2) ? c1 : c2;
}
var clr1 = setInterval(function() { flash('foo1', 'gray', 'red') }, 1000);
var clr2 = setInterval(function() { flash('foo2', 'gray', 'blue') }, 1000);
var clr3 = setInterval(function() { flash('foo3', 'gray', 'green') }, 1000);
```

and the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/che7Q/1/)** to go with it. You pass the ID of the element you want to flash and the two colors to alternate between.

Comment: can a value of a color be passed through the id tag? because I need to run this several times on a page using different base colors but each alternates with grey.

Comment: You could change the function and pass colors and the element to apply it to directly. I'll create another example for you.

Comment: this works good, but when i enter a color like `#ffffff` it flashes once and stops, only works if I enter names as the color. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript it is very simple:

```
function alternateColor(color, textId, myInterval) {
    if(!myInterval){
        myInterval = 1000;    
    }
    var colors = ['grey', color];
    var currentColor = 1;
    document.getElementById(textId).style.color = colors[0];
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById(textId).style.color = colors[currentColor];
        if (currentColor < colors.length-1) {
            ++currentColor;
        } else {
            currentColor = 0;
        }
    }, myInterval);
}
alternateColor('red','myText');
```

Call the function with the first argument being a color, the second being your text's ID, and third being the interval time (optional). [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hH9nu/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple easy to understand code.

```
var count_x = 1,
    max_x = 5;  // Change this for number of on-off flashes

var flash_color_notify = setInterval(function () {
    /* Change the color depending if it's even(= gray) or odd(=red) */
    if (count_x % 2 === 0) {    // even
        $('#element').css('color', 'gray');
    } else {                    // odd
        $('#element').css('color', 'red');
    }

    /* Clear the interval when completed blinking */
    if (count_x === max_x * 2) {
        clearInterval(flash_color_notify);
    } else { count_x += 1; }
}, 500);
```