# Call <a> tag from css into javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, hyperlink, tags, call

I am using [this changing color script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296298) by j08691:

```
function flash() {
var text = document.getElementById('foo');
text.style.color = (text.style.color=='red') ? 'green':'red';
}
var clr = setInterval(flash, 1000);
```

I  want to call the `<body>` tag and `<a>` tag from the CSS not an id.

For the `<body>` tag I did this and it works:

```
function flash() {
var text = document.body;
text.style.color = (text.style.color=='black') ? 'white':'black';
}
var clr = setInterval(flash, 1);
```

But it isn't working with the `<a>` tag. I tried variations like:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Instead of var `text = document.getElementById('a');` and replacing `text.style.color` with `links[i].style.color` or `links.style.color` but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing there.

I want to change the colors of all links at once.

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll('.a').style.color`

Comment: In jquery it is one step process. If possible try with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track - `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, so just loop through the collection:

```
function flash() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].style.color = (links[i].style.color=='black') ? 'white':'black';
    }
}
setInterval(flash, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1r4u3376/)

Also note that `setInterval` takes milliseconds, so `setInterval(x, 1)` isn't advised.

Comment: Thank you! Many thanks for this. This works perfectly. The Interval of 1 was for effect; I may set it to 10 or 100.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the a tags in the html? and then apply some css to each via your function?

Using the jquery library

```
$("a").each(function(){
//do something with the element here like your function.  $(this).stuff;
});
```

Comment: As the question was not tagged with `jquery`, quick intro to the library would be appropriate.